# In R, how can I build a list with some elements referring to earlier elements in the list?

Tags: r, list, environment

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
opts = list(
  width=128,
  overlap=width/2,
)
```

But, as expected, I get

```
Error: object 'width' not found
```

What is a good idiom for salvaging this code snippet?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was also hoping to find a solution along the lines of `opts = {width = 128; overlap = width/2; as.list(environment())}`. I couldn't figure out how to obtain just the assignments from the innermost frame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::lst` which is same as `list` but here you can build the components sequentially.

```
dplyr::lst(
  width = 128, 
  overlap=width/2,
)

#$width
#[1] 128

#$overlap
#[1] 64
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is:

```
opts = list(
  width={width<-128},
  overlap=width/2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, the best you might be able to do would be to define the list first with a width element, and then reuse it in a later assignment:

```
lst <- list(width=128)
lst$height <- lst$width / 2
lst

$width
[1] 128

$height
[1] 64
```